# Probability of a sequence of visits in Markov chain

Tags: probability, statistics, markov-chains, markov-process

I have 9 x 9 Markov chain state transition matrix. There are 5 states which are visited just once, and then the chain iterates through the remaining 4 states indefinitely. I have calculated the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $\mathbf{T}$. Of the remaining 4 states, 2 are special. I would like to find the probability that there are $n$ consecutive visits to the special states. How can I find this probability?

Comment: Do you know the transition probabilities?

Comment: The 4 states must have 0 probability transitioning to the other 5, so you have a block matrix where you can fix quite many 0s in it.

Comment: Yes, I know the transition probabilities between the 4 states